# HttpClient Gzip Compression

Tags: c#, azure, compression, httpclient, gzip

I have the following code running that calls an API, decompresses the response and then converts it to an object:

```
 public static async Task<List<marketData>> GetAllEvents()
    {
        string res = "";

        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip;

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://services.betvictor.com/omds/events/query/sport/200/markettypes/6/periods/-1.json?ep=true&e=true"))
            {                    
                Stream dataStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    res = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                }

                dataStream.Close();
                dataStream.Dispose();                 
            }
        }

        handler.Dispose();

        getEvents.Rootobject rawdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<getEvents.Rootobject>(res);
        return sortMarketsAndRaces(rawdata);
    }
```

This all runs absolutely fine when running on localhost, but when deploying using an Azure Server I get the error:

> "The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression
>   method."

Stacktrace:

> at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(FlushCode flushCode)  at
>   System.IO.Compression.Inflater.ReadInflateOutput(Byte* bufPtr, Int32
>   length, FlushCode flushCode, Int32& bytesRead)  at
>   System.IO.Compression.Inflater.InflateVerified(Byte* bufPtr, Int32
>   length)  at
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.FinishReadAsyncMemory(ValueTask`1
>   readTask, Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  at
>   System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBufferAsync()  at
>   System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEndAsyncInternal()  at
>   tf.PriceService.Core.Classes.BetVictorMatching.GetAllEvents() in
>   C:\Data\tf-price-service\src\tf.PriceService.Core\Classes\BetVictorMatching.cs:line
>   228  at
>   tf.PriceService.Core.Services.PriceService.<>c.<b__53_6>d.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Data\tf-price-service\src\tf.PriceService.Core\Services\PriceService.cs:line
>   253  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown ---  at
>   tf.PriceService.Core.Services.PriceService.getAllBookmakerMeetingsAndRaces(DateTime
>   date) in
>   C:\Data\tf-price-service\src\tf.PriceService.Core\Services\PriceService.cs:line
>   255  at
>   tf.PriceService.Core.Services.PriceService.processRacePrices(Object
>   state) in
>   C:\Data\tf-price-service\src\tf.PriceService.Core\Services\PriceService.cs:line
>   308

Comment: Azure Server: Virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the IP of the Azure server not being on the API whitelist therefore it was returning a 403 forbidden error in the response.